# 0's Not being Stripped from the front of a numeric value

Tags: php, for-loop, int

I am working on a project for a friend's website which is suppose to generate completely random phone numbers to be displayed on a "fake" review board. I figured the best way to do with would be for me to to generate out each section separably. So 3-3-4, but no matter what I do, every time there is a 0 in front the code cuts it off. Here's an example of what I mean:

http://www.shiningashes.net/Test.php

yet this is what I have for the code:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0000; $i <= 9999; $i++) {
echo $i;
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

How do I get the 0's to stop being cropped out so the 0's display? 0001, 0021, 0123, etc?

Comment: If your total integer size is 4, you could count how long the string you get is, and add the difference to 4 in zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 9999; $i++) {
   echo str_pad($i, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
   echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use printf to format your output:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= 9999; $i++) {
  printf("%04d<br>\n",$i);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your variable a string if you want to keep the zeros. That would mean using quotes, and never using numeric operators on it. But since you depend on using ++ on it, I suggest the following hack:

```
<?php
for ($i = 10000; $i <= 19999; $i++) {
    $str=substr ( $i , 0 , 4 );
    echo $i;
    echo $str;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This is extremely longwinded. There are quite a few built-in functions that you could use, ranging from printf/sprintf (see answer above), money_format or str_pad.

Comment: I went with the str_pad method posted above. Works perfectly for what I need it for. Thanks everyone.

Comment: To say it is "longwinded" is a highly opinionated claim. The cleanest code is not the shortest.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert your integer to a string when printing it.

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= 9999; $i++) {
    printf("%04d<br />", $i);
 }
 ?>
```

Check the documentation for printf/sprintf for more information.
Kind regards,
Stefan